# Не получается разархивировать arj архив, выходит пустой файл

Tags: java, архивация

Не пойму, как доделать функцию. Пользуюсь Apache Commons Compress.
Суть проблемы: не получается должным образом разархивировать ARJ архив.
Сделал функцию, она у меня разархивирует, но по сути получается что просто создает пустые файлы находящиеся в архиве с тем же расширением, именем и размером, но пустые.

Как мне сделать, что бы разархивировались целые файлы, я пока что не пойму. Подскажите где копать...

Еще когда начинаю читать файл `stream.read()`ом , то выводит исключение о том, что "метод сжатия не поддерживается" и ругается на эту строку.

```
public void unarj(String arjFile, String outt) throws ArchiveException, Exception {

    try (ArjArchiveInputStream stream = new ArjArchiveInputStream(new FileInputStream(arjFile))) {
        System.out.println(stream.toString());
        ArjArchiveEntry entry;
        String name;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while ((entry = stream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            name = entry.getName();
            final File archiveEntry = new File(outt, name);
            archiveEntry.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                archiveEntry.mkdir();
            }
            int tmp;
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(archiveEntry);
            while ((tmp = stream.read()) != -1)
            {
                out.write((char) tmp);
            }
        }
        stream.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Какую версию использовали?

Comment: использую версию 1.18

Comment: Хорошо бы и пример Arj архива получить, с которым у вас проблемы.

Comment: К сожалению Apache Commons Compress не поддерживает компрессию в Arj архивах https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/limitations.html

Comment: -поддержка только для чтения.
Мне и не нужно делать компрессию, мне наоборот нужна декомпрессия, тут она вроде доступна, как я понимаю, или я что то не так понимаю)?

Comment: Arj имеет несколько уровней компрессии. Apache Commons Compress поддерживает чтение лишь самого простого, когда файлы вообще не сжаты. В вашем же архиве файлы сжаты и поэтому Apache Commons Compress открыть их не может.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь все ясно.

Comment: @РостиславКрасный оформите в ответ?

Comment: @AntonSorokin оформил.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, текущая версия Apache Commons Compress [не поддерживает](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/limitations.html) компрессию в Arj архивах.

Поэтому этой библиотекой вы не можете распаковывать файлы, находящиеся в Arj архиве в сжатом виде. Apache Commons Compress поддерживает распаковку лишь несжатых файлов.